# Check the value not exists in a column for group of records in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table which store data respective to a unique id which clups multiple records to make it a part of the group.
I want to check whether in that group a value exists for a column but not in other column.
I tried with group by clause, where clause but i am not getting the expected records. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  id Group receiver sender sender_role
    1   a      Val1    Val2  Guest
    2   a      Val1    Val2  Guest
    3   b      Val3    Val4  CC
    4   b      Val4    Val3  Guest
    5   b      Val4    Val3  Guest
    6   c      Val5    Val6  Guest
```

In above table I need to group the chat and find in that group a name should exist in recevier but not in sender at all.

Here in group **a** for example looking for **Val1**, so it matches the condition of being in reciever and not in sender at all.

```
 1   a      Val1    Val2  Guest
 2   a      Val1    Val2  Guest
```

Here in group **b** for example looking for Val3, so it not matches the condition as Val3 exists in both reciever and sender.

```
3   b      Val3    Val4  CC
4   b      Val4    Val3  Guest
5   b      Val4    Val3  Guest
```

Here in group **c** for example looking for Val5, so it  matches the condition as Val5 exists in reciever and not in sender.

```
6   c      Val5    Val6  Guest.
```

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward approach uses conditional aggregation to assert your conditions:

```
SELECT `Group`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `Group`
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN receiver = 'Val1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN sender   = 'Val1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

By the way, *don't* name your columns `Group`, otherwise you'll have to surround that column name with backticks every time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.group = t.group and t2.receiver = 'Val1'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.group = t.group and t2.sender = 'Val1'
                 );
```

This is for your first condition.  The rest are similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*
from your_table a
where not exists 
(select null from your_table b where
                  a.`group`=b.group and a.receiver=b.sender);
```

[Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84ed1d/3)